# Webdav access without davwwwroot in cnv path

Tags: 2013, webdav, network

One of our SharePoint customers got a bunch of hard links in his Navision to documents in SharePoint. The thing is that they link via WebDav \\hostname\site\doclib\file.extention

We just migrated there SharePoint 2010 to 2013, and after that process the files are no longer reachable. If i format the link \\hostname\davwwwroot\site\doclib\file.extention it works. As far as i know WebDav should work without the "davwwwroot" if one specify a following folder.

Now to the thing that really freaks me out. From the server it works fine without davwwwroot , BUT from the clients on the Network they can only reach the shares with "davwwwroot" in the path.

I hit the roadblock rather hard on this one, i'd appriciate any pointers to as if where i might have gone wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this specific issue, but when I have run into SharePoint WebDav issues in the past it has come down to one of two issues.

The first is that if the WebDav IIS 7 role is enabled, it causes conflicts with SharePoint WebDav. This article shows how to enable WebDav for various IIS versions, but you should be able to use it to figure out if you have WebDav enabled and then disable it: http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis

The other issue is the URLScan ISAPI filter as explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briangre/archive/2011/11/17/urlscan-intereferes-with-webdav.aspx. I don't think this is your issue, but it's worth checking too.

Comment: Thankyou for the sudgestions, however none of the links seems related to the issue at hand. WebDav is allready disabled in the IIS, and i have removed the WebDav publishing feature from the IIS installation to make sure there is no conflict. WebDav is working propperly with SharePoint when DavWWWRoot is included, the only thing not working is CNV path without including DavWWWRoot in the path from clients (on the same Network)